# How to add padding in the middle of a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to change the following type of string

```
A1.01.01
```

to

```
A01.01.01
```

by adding a zero in the first section divided by `.`. The string always starts with `A`. The number following A can be single digit or double digits. The padding is only required for single digit. So for things like `A11.01.01`, I want to keep them as they are.

How do I do that with regex in Python

Comment: Will it always be an A at the beginning? Could it have more than one letter? What if there already is a zero to start, like A01? Do you want to add another zero, or leave it as is?

Comment: @jdaz, always starts with `A`, if the number is 1-9, there is never leading zero

Comment: Ok so why not use something like `string = "A1.01.01"; newString = "A0" + string[1:]`

Comment: @jdaz because I don't want to pad something like `A11.01.01`

Comment: You could replace the zero-width string matched of the regular expression `r'(?<=^A)'` with the string `"0"`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/zlVCEv/1/).

Comment: When responding to comments that request clarification please edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. Questions should stand alone and should not require readers to read through all the comments to understand what you want to do. It is still not clear whether `'A'` must be followed by a digit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland what does `?<=` mean?

Comment: It's a positive lookbehind. `(?<=^A)` means that the the match must be immediately preceded by `'A'` at the beginning of the string (`^`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `sub()` function of the `re` module. Try with the following:

```
text = 'A1.01.01'
re.sub(r'^A(\d{1})\.', r'A0\1.', text)
```

Comment: Why is the dot escaped in the first part but not the second part? What does `\1` mean in second part?

Comment: The dot is escaped in the first part because is part of a regex pattern (the first arg of the `sub()` function is indeed a regex pattern). In the second part it's not necessary because it's not a regex anymore. The `\1` holds the content of the first group captured in the regex pattern of the first argument of the `sub()` function. (in this case: the digit)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simpler than regex:

```
string = "A1.01.01"

newString = "A0" + string[1:] if len(string.split(".")[0]) == 2 else string
```

Comment: This will work. However I need to replace strings in a column of Pandas dataframe. using replace is much faster than apply

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function format(str) {
      return str.replace(/^(A)(\d){1}(\.)(.*)/g, "$10$2.$4");
    }
```

[CheckThis](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHAKPELFK206)

Comment: what is `/gim`?

Comment: g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match) i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
M for multiline search

Comment: g is only needed in your case. So i updated the answer.

Comment: Working as per ur requirement, right?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question, I learnt something new doing this.

```
import re

s = "A1.01.01"
pattern = re.sub(r"(?<!0)\d(?=\.)",r"0\g<0>",s)
```

This'll do it.

Comment: This works for 'A1.01.01' but not something like 'A11.01.01'. I want to keep the latter format unchanged and only pad the single digit

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, if the string begins with `'A'` followed a digit followed by a period, the character `'0'` is to be inserted between `'A'` and the digit that follows.

You can do that by matching a zero-width string with the regular expression

```
r'(?<=^A)(?=\d\.)'
```

and replacing the match with `'0'`.

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/zlVCEv/3/) | [Python code](http://tpcg.io/oHAgYrDm)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=^A)   : positive lookbehind asserts that the current
          : position is preceded by 'A' at the beginning
          : of the string
(?=\d\.)  : positive lookahead asserts current position is
          : followed by a digit followed by '.'
```